# Blank page when deploying react-table on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, react-table

I am making simple `react.js` app using [react-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/).
I tried to run it locally using `npm start` and it is working fine.

But when I tried to deploy it on **github pages**, it just shows a blank page. I have followed all the steps for [deploying react app on gh pages](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f).

Here is the gh repository : https://github.com/7phalange7/react-table
the `main` branch has the project code, and `gh-pages` branch is deployed on github pages.

**Should there be a problem deploying `react-table` on github pages ?**

`package.json` for reference

```
{
  "name": "react-table-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "homepage": "https://7phalange7.github.io/react-table/"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Edit :
still not sure what is the issue here, but I copied all the code to a new react project and then deployed on github pages and it is working fine now. I guess since this was the first time deploying react project, somehow I messed up something.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the private to 'false' in your package.json